# Difference between logical volume and physical volume

Tags: linux, partitioning, storage

These are various terms used in Storage virtualization which can be very confusing as to their hierarchies and meaning. Please explain each of the following terms and the difference between them if any

1. Physical extent.
2. Logical extent.
3. Physical volume.
4. Logical volume.
5. Physical volume group.
6. Logical volume group.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_volume_management. This article is helpful but fully does not explain the differences completely.

Comment: This can depend on the software you use. Each software has somewhat different terminology. Can you add this information to your post?

Comment: Have you tried searching this information yourself? In first few hits with "linux lvm" in any search engine you're bound to bump on [Linux LVM HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/) which has definitions for terms you've listed (and some more).